# Rotate an image in opencv by c++ without scaling image

Tags: c++, opencv, scale, image-rotation

I use OpenCV 2.4 by C++. I have a binary image that uses `minAreaRect` function to find it's angle, like:

```
    RotatedRect BodyRec = minAreaRect(PointsOfbinaryImage);
    angle=BodyRec.angle;

    if (angle < -45.)
        angle += 90.;
        result.Angle=angle;

    //calculate Center 
    result.Center=BodyRec.center;
```

Now, I want to rotate image without scaling image.
I use this code:

```
    // Get rotation matrix for rotating the image around its center
Point2f center22(RGBsrc.cols/2.0, RGBsrc.rows/2.0);
Mat rot = getRotationMatrix2D(center22, result.Angle, 1.0);
// determine bounding rectangle
Rect bbox = RotatedRect(center22,RGBsrc.size(), result.Angle).boundingRect();
// adjust transformation matrix
rot.at<double>(0,2) += bbox.width/2.0 - center22.x;
rot.at<double>(1,2) += bbox.height/2.0 - center22.y;

Mat dst;
warpAffine(RGBsrc, dst, rot, bbox.size());
imshow("rotated_im", dst);
```

But my image was scale.
Main image:
[image: Main image]
Rotated image:
[image: Rotated and scale image]

What must I do?

Comment: The content of your image is not scaled. It's just an optical effect, since your second image is smaller (you set the `bbox`)